# which way is better, or more correct, and why?

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

In WPF there are many ways to achieve the same thing. In this example which is better?

```xml
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

or

```xml
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I'm guessing the first if you wanted to use it as a datatemplate for itemscontrol's

Comment: Obviously the one that has less code and more readable is more correct and better until proofed otherwise.

Comment: Until you actually -need- to template, don't use templating. =)

Comment: You forgot the option to use a style to change the template.

Comment: As in setting the ControlTemplate through a style? I wouldn't think that's really an option you'd consider when you have the choice of these two

Comment: @J.Steen please put your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you actually -need- to template, don't use templating. =)

That said, my highly personal rule of thumb is that if I'm repeating the same work more than two times (i.e., three and up) I probably need to template or implement some other lovely DRY principle.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a better solution

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate> 
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is because unlike `ItemsControl` or `ItemsPresenter`, `StackPanel` supports the `IScrollInfo` interface, and therefore you could exert a lot more control over how your items are scrolled.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo.aspx

Comment: assuming you want your items presented in a stackpanel.
also, i'm not sure fixed height is a better solution? well I prefer not to anyway

Comment: If you are going to use an ItemsControl, use a VirtualizingStackPanel  instead. It's indicated here:

Optimizing WPF Application Performance
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970683(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: An Itemscontrol as standard uses a non-virtualising stack panel by default, which is reflected in my answer. You would only use a virtualising stack panel if you wanted virtualisation behaviour.

Comment: The fixed height was unecessary, and I forgot to remove it from my demo before I copied my code. Have edited it out now